# networkd is not bringing eth0 up at boot

Tags: systemd, debian-jessie

I've installed Debian 8 on a gigabyte brix pro and everything seems to work properly except for networking.

I've enabled `systemd-networkd.service`, disabled `networking.service` and created the appropriate `network` files in `/etc/systemd/network`. I've configured and enabled `wpasupplicant` for the wireless adapter as well.

When the system boots, it finds the `wlan0.network` file, brings the interface up, detects a link and works perfectly but for some reason it doesn't see (or doesn't log that it sees) the `eth0.network` file I created. It does not detect a link and does not bring `eth0` up at all.

After the system is fully booted, I can run `systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service` or `ifup eth0` and it will bring the interface up and properly configure it at which point it works fine. It just won't bring it up on boot.

**/etc/systemd/network/wlan0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.21/24
DNS=192.168.1.1
```

**/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.10/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
DNS=192.168.1.1
```

**ip link**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:aa:14:db:cf:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:85:de:ee:96:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**lspci -v**

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
        I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Kernel driver in use: r8168
```

**journalctl**

```
kernel: r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.040.00-NAPI loaded
kernel: r8168 0000:03:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X

...

kernel: r8168: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
kernel: r8168  Copyright (C) 2015  Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com>
                    This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details, please see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
                    This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

...

systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : link 3 added
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : udev initialized link
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : flags change: +UP +RUNNING +MULTICAST +BROADCAST
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : flags change: -RUNNING
systemd-networkd[456]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=H
systemd-networkd[456]: sd-rtnl: discarding 20 bytes of incoming message
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : link state is up-to-date
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : found matching network '/etc/systemd/network/wlan0.network'
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : enslaved
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : setting addresses
systemd-networkd[456]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.2 object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=
systemd-networkd[456]: Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.2 object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAc
systemd-networkd[456]: sd-rtnl: discarding 20 bytes of incoming message
systemd-networkd[456]: rtnl: received address for a nonexistent link, ignoring
systemd-networkd[456]: rtnl: received address for a nonexistent link, ignoring
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : added address: 192.168.1.21/24
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : addresses set
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : link configured
```

**systemctl status systemd-networkd.service (from boot)**

```
systemd-networkd[456]: sd-rtnl: discarding 20 bytes of incoming message
systemd-networkd[456]: rtnl: received address for a nonexistent link, ignoring
systemd-networkd[456]: rtnl: received address for a nonexistent link, ignoring
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : added address: 192.168.1.21/24
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : addresses set
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : link configured
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : flags change: +LOWER_UP
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : flags change: +RUNNING
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : gained carrier
systemd-networkd[456]: wlan0           : added address: fe80::de85:deff:feee:96af/64
```

**systemctl status systemd-networkd.service (after restart of networkd)**

```
systemd-networkd[877]: wlan0           : link configured
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : flags change: +UP
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : added address: 192.168.1.10/24
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : addresses set
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : setting routes
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : routes set
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : link configured
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : flags change: +LOWER_UP +RUNNING
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : gained carrier
systemd-networkd[877]: eth0            : added address: fe80::feaa:14ff:fedb:cf40/64
```

What other information should I provide to help find a solution to this?

**UPDATE**

Adding the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces` and enabling `networking.service` fixes the issue and everything comes up at boot but I would rather not use the old init.d system. I want to use the new systemd-networkd and I'd like to know why this is happening in that environment.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

**EDIT**

`wpa_supplicant.service` is missing because I've since disabled it and `networking.service` is enabled because it's the only thing that is currently working.

**systemctl -t service**

```
UNIT                                            LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
acpid.service                                   loaded active running ACPI event daemon
atd.service                                     loaded active running Deferred execution scheduler
console-setup.service                           loaded active exited  LSB: Set console font and keymap
cron.service                                    loaded active running Regular background program processing daemon
dbus.service                                    loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
exim4.service                                   loaded active running LSB: exim Mail Transport Agent
getty@tty1.service                              loaded active running Getty on tty1
kbd.service                                     loaded active exited  LSB: Prepare console
keyboard-setup.service                          loaded active exited  LSB: Set preliminary keymap
kmod-static-nodes.service                       loaded active exited  Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel
lm-sensors.service                              loaded active exited  Initialize hardware monitoring sensors
networking.service                              loaded active exited  LSB: Raise network interfaces.
nfs-common.service                              loaded active exited  LSB: NFS support files common to client and server
rc-local.service                                loaded active exited  /etc/rc.local Compatibility
rpcbind.service                                 loaded active running LSB: RPC portmapper replacement
rsyslog.service                                 loaded active running System Logging Service
ssh.service                                     loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server
systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service loaded active exited  Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0
systemd-journald.service                        loaded active running Journal Service
systemd-logind.service                          loaded active running Login Service
systemd-modules-load.service                    loaded active exited  Load Kernel Modules
systemd-networkd.service                        loaded active running Network Service
systemd-random-seed.service                     loaded active exited  Load/Save Random Seed
systemd-remount-fs.service                      loaded active exited  Remount Root and Kernel File Systems
systemd-resolved.service                        loaded active running Network Name Resolution
systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service                  loaded active exited  Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0
systemd-setup-dgram-qlen.service                loaded active exited  Increase datagram queue length
systemd-sysctl.service                          loaded active exited  Apply Kernel Variables
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service              loaded active exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                  loaded active exited  Create Volatile Files and Directories
systemd-udev-trigger.service                    loaded active exited  udev Coldplug all Devices
systemd-udevd.service                           loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager
systemd-update-utmp.service                     loaded active exited  Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
systemd-user-sessions.service                   loaded active exited  Permit User Sessions
udev-finish.service                             loaded active exited  Copy rules generated while the root was ro
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `systemctl -t service`? You may have another service trying to setup the network at boot.

Comment: @MetaNova added the requested information

Comment: Also, did you accidentally omit the gateway parameter in your wlan0 network file?

Comment: Also if this is running a graphical environment it would be much easier to install NetworkManager and the appropriate applet for your DE. Reading about it seems this may just be a bug in the kernel.

Comment: @MetaNova No, I intentionally left the `Gateway` parameter out of `wlan0` Both interfaces are on the same segment and wlan0 has no need to go out the gateway. No, I don't have a desktop environment installed; this is a very lightweight headless server.

Comment: Ah, OK. NetworkManager is still a decent choice as it has an ncurses interface, but it certainly isn't as KISS as networkd.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why adding a stanza to `/etc/networking/interfaces` solves your problem is that you have the `networking.service` enabled. If you look at the `networking.service` file, you will see (partly edited):

```
[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/networking
Description=LSB: Raise network interfaces.
.....
[Service]
.....
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/networking start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/networking stop
ExecReload=/etc/init.d/networking reload
```

which clearly shows this is the service that provides compatibility with the old SysV script, which you wish to avoid.

Though this is not clearly stated anywhere (that I could find!), my guess is that this conflicts with `systemd-networkd.service`, which can provide exactly the same service, albeit without the compatibility with SysV.

So my guess is to disable `networking`, and to reboot to check that this is (the only piece of) the solution.

Comment: I'm not asking why it WORKS with `networking.service`, I'm asking why it DOESN'T work with `systemd-networkd.service`. I have `networking.service` enabled and configured right now because that's all that works. When I use `systemd-networkd.service` by itself, it does not work at all. So, to answer your question: When booting with `networking.service` disabled, the interface does not come up on boot.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae OP did in fact specify that they disabled `networking.service` in the second sentence. I looked in the edit history to confirm and the first revision still stated that unambiguously IMO.  Seems like a harsh lecture to OP - consider maybe you were confused?

Answer (score 0):

Similiar symptoms here.

log `br0: DHCPv6 lease lost` made me suspicious:

```
root@lorank8:/home/bue# systemctl status systemd-networkd
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-03-08 09:02:14 UTC; 2min 42s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 906 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─906 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Mar 08 09:02:22 lorank8 systemd-networkd[906]: br0: Lost carrier
Mar 08 09:02:22 lorank8 systemd-networkd[906]: br0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Mar 08 09:02:27 lorank8 systemd-networkd[906]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 08 09:02:30 lorank8 systemd-networkd[906]: usb0: Gained carrier
Mar 08 09:02:30 lorank8 systemd-networkd[906]: usb1: Gained carrier
Mar 08 09:02:31 lorank8 systemd-networkd[906]: usb0: Gained IPv6LL
Mar 08 09:02:31 lorank8 systemd-networkd[906]: usb1: Gained IPv6LL
```

connman.service interfered with systemd-networkd

After disabling connman, bridge and eth0 came up on boot as expected.